# Invert of a shift operation - determine shift count used to generate value

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have code that generates a value from an initial value of 1 by using a left shift. At a different point in the code, I know the value generated and need to calculate the shift count used to generate the value.

In other words I need to determine the shift count used to generate the result of a shift operation by performing an operation on the value generated.

Is it possible to invert a shift operation of a base two variable without using a dedicated function? I am looking for the value of a shift count variable `y` when the shifted value, `x`, and result of the shift operation, `z`, are known.

Example:

```
x << y = z
1 << 6 = 64

z = 64 and x is 1 but what is y???  // how to calculate y, the shift count?
```

There are many solutions including `log(64)/log(2)`, but I would have to use `math.h`. I am looking for some sort of bitwise operation that is fast and doesn't require a function.

EDIT: Thank you for your answers! My question is answered, there is no way to this with a simple operation, my compiler does not have CTZ. BR

Comment: Are you talking about non-truncating shifts only? Is it guaranteed that the most significant bit of `x` has not been shifted out?

Comment: Yes. I set a register like this: registerValue = 1 << [0..6]; When I retrieve the register value, I have to revert that calcualtion.

Comment: A simple loop of O(size of operand in bits) counting trailing zeros will do. Or builtin CTZ (count trailing zeros) if available.

Comment: An intrinsic function?

Comment: Or even a lookup table

Comment: I don't follow what it is that you are wanting to do. The example isn't really a C source code example and your comment uses the phrase "revert the calculation". It appears that what you want to do is to have a line or two of C source code which will take a value and then determine the shift count needed to transform a value of 1 into that value. Is that what you are wanting to do?

Comment: @RichardChambers I believe he is asking how to figure out `y` when given `x` and `z` from `z = x << y`.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, exactly. The example is not source code, otherwise I would have to write out functions. Arkku: I think you mean what i mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know `x` and `z` from `z = x << y`, and want to find out `y` using bitwise operations, a simple way would be to take `x` and shift it one bit at a time, comparing the result to `z` (i.e., start from `y = 0` and increment `y` by one after each failed comparison).

*edit*: On the other hand, if `x` is `1` (or indeed if `x` has the lowest bit set), you can also count the trailing zeroes in `z`. Your processor may have a single instruction for this, which your C compiler may expose as a non-portable extension, such as `__builtin_ctz` (you could consider using the pre-processor to toggle between this and a portable solution). There are also faster, portable solutions to this problem than the trivial loop – search for "count trailing zeroes".

(In cases where `x` does not have the lowest bit set, one might count the trailing zeroes in both `x` and `z` to find out the difference.)

Comment: This is a solution using a function. I was looking for something smaller, like mentioned some sort of bitwise operation. It is easy to do it the other way around, but I could not find and "elegant" solution for getting y out of z, where z is a number with base 2.

Comment: There is no single bitwise operation for this. On some architectures CTZ is implemented as a single machine instruction.

Comment: @Arkku yes! Sorry, i mixed that up.

Comment: @earthling Then see edit (CTZ), and Eugene Sh.'s comment above. (And maybe https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear)

Comment: @Arkku the other post was deleted, so here my answer: I will word my next question better and give a better example. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single operation or function in standard C that computes the number of trailing zero bits in an integer.  You can perform such a computation by checking one bit at a time via a loop, as other answers have suggested.  If you need to do it a lot, though, then you might want a more efficient alternative, such as this:

```
int trailing_zero_bits(uint64_t x) {
    uint64_t bits = ~(uint64_t)0;
    int rval = 0;

    for (int shift = 32; shift; shift >>= 1) {
        bits >>= shift;
        if (!(x & bits)) {
            rval += shift;
            x >>= shift;
        }
    }

    return rval + !x;  // The !x adds 1 if x is zero at this point
}
```

That loop will iterate exactly 6 times, *vs.* up to 63 times for the 64-bit bit-at-a-time alternative.

Of course, there may be system- or environment-specific alternatives that are even more efficient.

Comment: Is this really more efficient taking in account the number of operations done each loop?

Comment: It depends on the number of trailing zeroes, @EugeneSh.  I count 6 arithmetic operations, 4 assignment operations, and two tests for each of exactly 6 iterations in the above.  I count 3 arithmetic operations, 2 assignments, and 1 test per iteration in `while (x & 1) { r++; x>>=1; }`, with as many iterations as there are trailing zeroes, plus 1.  By those counts, mine is winning by the time we get to 11 trailing zeroes.  If the shift we are trying to compute is uniformly distributed in the range 0 - 63, then my version wins more than 80% of the time, and on average.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative function ideas can use a switch statement as in:

```
int trailing_zero_bits(uint64_t x) {
    int iRetVal = 0;

    switch (x & 0x7f) {
    case 2:
        iRetVal = 1;
        break;
    case 4:
        iRetVal = 2;
        break;
    case 8:
        iRetVal = 3;
        break;
    case 16:
        iRetVal = 4;
        break;
    case 32:
        iRetVal = 5;
        break;
    case 64:
        iRetVal = 6;
        break;
    default:
        iRetVal = 0;
    }

    return iRetVal;
}
```

And this could be condensed down using [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) to:

```
int trailing_zero_bits(uint64_t x) {
    int iRetVal = 0;

    switch (x & 0x3f) {
        case 64:  iRetVal++;
        case 32:  iRetVal++;
        case 16:  iRetVal++;
        case 8:  iRetVal++;
        case 4:  iRetVal++;
        case 2:  iRetVal++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return iRetVal;
}
```

Or you could take a lookup table approach as in:

```
int trailing_zero_bits(uint64_t x) {
    unsigned char  x1[9] = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3 };
    unsigned char  x2[9] = { 0, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    return x1[x & 0xf] | x2[(x & 0x70) >> 4];
}
```

Or alternatively

```
int trailing_zero_bits(uint64_t x) {
    unsigned short x1[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40 };
    unsigned short xVal = (unsigned short)(x & 0x7f);
    int  i = 0;

    if (xVal) for (i = 0; (x1[i] & xVal) == 0; i++);

    return i;
}
```

Or eliminate the table with:

```
int trailing_zero_bits(uint64_t x) {
    unsigned short x1 = 0x01;
    unsigned short xVal = (unsigned short)(x & 0x7f);
    int  i = 0;

    if (xVal) for (i = 0; (x1 & xVal) == 0; i++, (x1 <<= 1));

    return i;
}
```

Or back to using a table but with pointers to eliminate indexing:

```
int trailing_zero_bits(uint64_t x) {
    unsigned short x1[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40};
    unsigned short *x2 = x1;
    unsigned short xVal = (unsigned short)(x & 0x7f);

    if (xVal) for ( ; (*x2 & xVal) == 0; x2++);

    return (x2 - x1);
}
```

Comment: For my case this solution is too complex, as I will only handle 6 shifts max. However I really like this answer, also Duff's Device was an interesting read. Thanks.

Comment: @earthling your question was relaxing to think about and to consider unusual approaches so thank you for the exercise! When I first came across Duff's Device, I was dumb founded by the simplicity of it and how it took advantage of the C specification. It's a really neat way of reconsidering the `switch` statement.

Comment: happy to have provided a brain teaser, you provided yours with your answer for me :) Thanks also.